# Search and replace each unique word that begins with @ symbol in string, even if they're similar

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace all occurrences in the string starting with @. If i use str_replace everything works fine until the usernames becomes similar. I need something to replace the exact unique words in full, without affecting other similar words. Example @johnny and @johnnys would be problematic. Maybe regex could help?

```
function myMentions($str){
    $str = "Hello @johnny, how is @johnnys doing?"; //let's say this is our param

     $regex = "~(@\w+)~"; //my regex to extract all words beginning with @ 

            if(preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)){ 

                foreach($matches[1] as $matches){ //iterate over match results

    $link = "<a href='www.google.com'>$matches</a>"; //wrap my matches in links

    $str = str_replace($matches,$link,$str); //replace matches with links

    }
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Output should be: `Hello <a href=''>@johnny</a>, how is <a href=''>@johnnys</a> doing?`

Instead i am getting: `Hello <a href=''>@johnny</a>, how is <a href=''>@johnny</a> s doing?` 
(NOTE: The extra "s" on @johnnys isn't wrap)

It doesn't recognize that @johnny and @johnnys are two different words, so str_replace both words with in one go. Basically the function is taking one word and replacing all similar words at once.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem? What are the rules behind this replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unnecessarily complex, you just need a mere `preg_replace`:

```
function myMentions($str){
     return preg_replace("~@\w+~", "<a href='www.google.com'>\$0</a>", $str);
}

$str = "Hello @johnny, how is @johnnys doing?";
echo myMentions($str);
// => Hello <a href='www.google.com'>@johnny</a>, how is <a href='www.google.com'>@johnnys</a> doing?
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/ecFln).

The `preg_replace("~@\w+~", "<a href='www.google.com'>\$0</a>", $str)` matches all non-overlapping occurrences of `@` + 1 or more word chars, and wraps them with `<a href='www.google.com'>` and `</a>` texts. Note the `$0` is a backreference to the whole match.

Comment: I have to work in a foreach because i am gonna put each user id in the link. Your solution worked for wrapping all the similar words, but each words that are similar are returning the same id in foreach, so now i am gonna work on solving this. Thanks alot mate :)

Comment: @XpressPHP You do not need any foreach. If you retrieve values by passing the mention value as key to some dictionary (associative array, say `$dic = ['johnny' => '300923','johnnys' => '999923']`) you need `return preg_replace_callback("~@(\w+)~", function($m) use ($dic) {
         return "<a href='www.google.com/" . $dic[$m[1]] . "'>" . $m[0] . "</a>";
     }, $str);`. See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/2hq6E).